# Detect duplicate string or word in a row

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know how to detect duplicate word in a row. This is to ensure that we have clean data in our database.

For example see below

```
Name                            count
James James McCarthy            1
Donald Hughes Hughes            1
```

I want the result to be like

```
Name                     count
James McCarthy            1
Donald Hughes             1
```

Is there a solution to this using Oracle SQL?

Comment: you want to *detect* or **detect and modify** duplicate text in a row

Comment: What have you tried? There are some common techniques to tokenize a string, and counting each token is then fairly simple. It isn't clear if you want to count and identify them, or replace duplicates; also not clear if they have to be adjacent (what would you do with `'James McCarthy James'`?). It's also possible someone might actually have a repeated part of their name. (Boutros Boutros-Ghal was the first example that came to mind, but the hyphen may or may not rule that out of your 'cleaning'; [here are some others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_with_reduplicated_names)).

Comment: Thank you so Vikrant. I actually do want to identify them and see how often we have this kind of data. I know some people do have same name as last and first name and thats the reason why we wont want to alter them. But if i can get a way to identify them will be helpful. I have tried using regexp_like but i was getting and invalid identifier error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adjacent words

```
select  1
from    dual
where   regexp_like ('John John Doe','(^|\s)(\S+)\s+\2(\s|$)')
;
```

or

```
select  case when regexp_like ('John John Doe','(^|\s)(\S+)\s+\2(\s|$)') then 'Y' end as adj_duplicate
from    dual
;
```

Comment: Thanks, i am not actually replacing them. i want to identify them

Comment: what if i want to query from a table directly and not from dual.

Comment: @AbimbolaFolorunso, replace dual with you table and the hard-coded string with your column - `select  case when regexp_like (my_column,'(^|\s)(\S+)\s+\2(\s|$)') then 'Y' end as adj_duplicate from my_table`